# sequelize - is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have an object List that should contain ListEntries. This is my code so far:

models/List.js

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports=function(sequelize, DataTypes){
  return List = sequelize.define("List", {

      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      }
    }, {
      freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
      classMethods:{

      }
    })
};
```

models/ListEntry.js

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");


module.exports=function(sequelize, DataTypes){
  return ListEntry = sequelize.define("ListEntry", {

    entry: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
    classMethods:{

    }
  })
};
```

models/index.js

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");


var sequelize = new Sequelize('development', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

var models = [
  'List', 'ListEntry'
];
models.forEach(function(model) {
  module.exports[model] = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/../models/' + model);
});

var List = require('../models/').List;
var ListEntry = require('../models/').ListEntry;

List.hasMany(ListEntry, {as: 'Notes'});

List.sync()
ListEntry.sync()
```

But if I now want to get all the ListEntries from List in a controller, I get an error:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  List.getNotes().then(function(bla){

  });

});


List.getNotes is not a function
```

[image]

Comment: How do you require `List` in the controller ?

Comment: Oh sorry. With `var List = require('../models/').List;`

Comment: You need to pass your `sequelize` from `models/index` as argument to each of your models. The error is coming from `...sequelize.define("List"...` because inside that code block `sequelize` is indeed not an function, it is `undefined`

Comment: @MiroslavSaracevic what do you mean? I can't follow. The code works as it creates tables. I was even able to insert a List and could also read from the db

Comment: sorry, I misread, I figured that error you were getting is that sequelize is not a function from title, didn't see the last line in your question. Can you post your entire router including path to router file?

Comment: I've added a screenshot